# How do I pass a bool variable from form2 back to form1?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a bool variable from form 2 and place it into form 1.  How would you do this?

Answer (score 3):

1 ,  By instance parameter

```
  bool flg = false;
  form1 f1 = new form1(flg);
  f1.show();
```

2,  By the public property.

```
  form1 f1 = new form1();
  f1.FLG = false;
  f1.show();
```

3,  By the public set method

```
  form1 f1 = new form1();
  f1.SetFlg(false);
  f1.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write public `property/method` to return (exchange) data between forms. First of all you need to understand - How to access properties/methods of an object of one class from the methods/properties of an object of another class?

For instance, create a public property say `Status` in `Form2` class,

```
public partial class Form2
{
  ...
  private bool _status; 
  public bool Status
   {
    get
     {
      return _status;
     }
    set
    {
      _status=value;
     }
   }
  ....
}
```

Now, if you want to get the value of `Status` property  from within the Form1 method.

```
public partial class Form1
{
   ....
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Form2 frm=new Form2();
    frm.ShowDialog();
    bool status=frm.Status;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a beginners question, so your answer should explain that a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an interface.

```
 public interface IForm
 {
    bool GetResult();
 }
 // form 2
 public partial class Form2 : Form, IForm (...)
 private bool Result;
 public bool GetResult()
 {
  return Result;
 }

 // form 1
 var form2 = new Form2();
 ((IForm)form2).GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//In Form1 define global static bool variable
Form1
{ 

public static bool variable;

}

// In Form2 call it
Form2
{
   Form1.variable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Form 1:

```
//Create global variable
public bool test;
//Initialize the form
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Form 2:

```
Form1 originalForm;
public Form2(Form1 incomingForm)
{
    originalForm = incomingForm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Set or get like this:
`originalForm.test`

Hope it works